# Make extendable fastAPI query class

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, pydantic

Im trying to have a base query class to reuse according to the different use cases

```
from fastapi.params import Query
class BaseParams:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str = Query(alias="name", description="name", example="Bob"),
        age: int = Query(alias="age", description="age", example=18),
        # ... more base fields
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        # ...
```

then have something like

```
class TeacherParams(BaseParams):
    def __init__(
        self,
        salary: int = Query(default=None, description="Salary", example=100000),
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.salary = salary

class StudentParams(BaseParams):
    def __init__(
        self,
        classes: list[str] = Query(default=["math"], description="Classes", example=["math"]),
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.classes = classes


@app.get("/students", tags=["students"])
async def students(request: Request, params: StudentParams = Depends()):
    # do stuffs

@app.get("/teachers", tags=["teachers"])
async def teachers(request: Request, params: TeacherParams = Depends()):
    # do stuffs

# ...
```

This approach is not working as I may expect.

the `StudentParams` | `TeacherParams` are not having the fields from the BaseParams, only the specific on each.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TeacherParams(BaseParams):
     def __init__(
        self,
        salary: int = Query(default=None, description="Salary", example=100000),
        **kwargs,
):
        kwargs_dict = json.loads(kwargs['kwargs'])
        super().__init__(**kwargs_dict)
        self.salary = salary


class StudentParams(BaseParams):
     def __init__(
        self,
        classes: list[str] = Query(default=["math"], description="Classes", example=["math"]),
        **kwargs,
):
       kwargs_dict = json.loads(kwargs['kwargs'])
       super().__init__(**kwargs_dict)
       self.classes = classes
```

The following modifications have been made to the code:

In the TeacherParams and StudentParams classes, the kwargs parameter is passed as a dictionary,which contains the key-value pairs for the parameters. However, this format is not directly usable, it's look like this `{'kwargs': '{"name":"username", "age":26}'}`, as it cannot be easily unpacked into separate key-value pairs. To resolve this issue, the kwargs_dict variable is created using the json.loads() method, which converts the string in the kwargs dictionary to a dictionary format, which results in `{"name":"username", "age":26}'}`. This allows for easy unpacking of the key-value pairs and use in the parent class.

Additionally, it is just a suggetion to remove the args parameter from the child classes if it is not required, as query parameters can be directly passed to the constructor.

Comment: What makes you think a keyword argument named `kwargs` will be present at all, let alone be a JSON string? And why would that contain the base class' constructor arguments?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not getting your point correctly, As per my understanding because I'm accepting `**kwargs` in child class so it will be present and I'm calling base class constructor and passing the extra params which received in `kwargs` dict.
That's what I understood from your comment.  if you have any further discussion then please explain me your question in deep.